# Unable to establish connection with Db2 via its VScode extension

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am currently using the Db2 Connect extension for VScode on a Windows 11. I did not installed any IBM package or Db2 driver, since I was unable to determine which one to pick and where to get it.

I have created a credential within an instance on my Db2 Lite account and as well created a profile on the Db2 Connect extension. I doubled checked all the information related to Db2 instance when creating the profile on Db2 Connect.

When I try to connect with my Db2 instance through the Db2 Connect on VScode, I get this error prompted:

**'Connection to database failed: Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0157E Error opening a file. SQLSTATE=HY507'**

I did search about this, and stumbled on this web page [https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdse/6.4.0?topic=replication-command-line-interface-error](https://stackoverflow.com), though I was unable to determine which terminal I am supposed to enter those commands.

Also, I tried the command **db2level** on PWSH and it did not recognize it, so nothing is installed but the Db2 extension.

Please advise if I need to perform any additional installation to successfully connect with Db2,or any other suggestion to try out.

Comment: Which flavour of the Db2 extension did you install?  For connecting with Db2-on-cloud (lite), use the plain Db2.Connect.  When you are trying to connect, which option are you using?  A full connection string, or other?  Did you verify the connection string ? Does it contain Security=SSL; ?

Comment: Can you connect to the database using Dbeaver or any db client?

Comment: Works correctly for me in Win11, both with and without ssl encryption on the connection. Be aware that when you install the Db2.connect VSCODE extension via VScode marketplace, it automatically installs a tiny clidriver from IBM which does the work of connecting to the db. You do not need to install other software if your target DB is on cloud/LUW. You will get this error CLI0157E when there is something wrong with your connection string. You can manually create a db2dsdriver.cfg (or db2cli.ini) to compensate but that should be OPTIONAL.